# Read all the contents in ini file into dictionary with Python

Tags: python, configuration-files, ini

Normally, I code as follows for getting a particular item in a variable as follows

```
try:
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(self.iniPathName)
except ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError, e:
    raise WrongIniFormatError(`e`)

try:
    self.makeDB = config.get("DB","makeDB")
except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    self.makeDB = 0
```

Is there any way to read all the contents in a python dictionary?

For example

```
[A]
x=1
y=2
z=3
[B]
x=1
y=2
z=3
```

is written into

```
val["A"]["x"] = 1
...
val["B"]["z"] = 3
```

Comment: ConfigParser from Python 3 has this functionality, and you may use the [backport](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/) to have it in Python 2

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I suggest subclassing `ConfigParser.ConfigParser` (or `SafeConfigParser`, &c) to safely access the "protected" attributes (names starting with single underscore -- "private" would be names starting with *two* underscores, not to be accessed even in subclasses...):

```
import ConfigParser

class MyParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):

    def as_dict(self):
        d = dict(self._sections)
        for k in d:
            d[k] = dict(self._defaults, **d[k])
            d[k].pop('__name__', None)
        return d
```

This emulates the usual logic of config parsers, and is guaranteed to work in all versions of Python where there's a `ConfigParser.py` module (up to 2.7, which is the last of the `2.*` series -- knowing that there will be no future Python 2.any versions is how compatibility can be *guaranteed*;-).

If you need to support future Python `3.*` versions (up to 3.1 and probably the soon forthcoming 3.2 it should be fine, just renaming the module to all-lowercase `configparser` instead of course) it may need some attention/tweaks a few years down the road, but I wouldn't expect anything major.

Comment: Tried your answer and the keys are all lowercased.
e.g. for:
"""
[title]
KEY1 = VAL1
""""

I get in `config['title']`:

`{key1: VAL1}`

This is because the dictionary inside self_sections has lowercase keys in the first place so it appears... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359556/configparser-reads-capital-keys-and-make-them-lower-case

Comment: Seems like adding this to your class constructor solves the lowercase issue:
    `def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.optionxform = str`

Answer (score 36):

I managed to get an answer, but I expect there should be a better one.

```
dictionary = {}
for section in config.sections():
    dictionary[section] = {}
    for option in config.options(section):
        dictionary[section][option] = config.get(section, option)
```

Comment: I think this is a very good solution, why aren't you happy with it?

Comment: This should be the answer because it solves the problem without having to use the "private" "_sections" attribute. And, of course, if one needs to use an OrderedDict, just use that in place of the regular dict.

Comment: Replacing `dictionary` with a `defaultdict(dict)` would remove the intermediate dict creation.

Answer (score 24):

I know that this question was asked 5 years ago, but today I've made this dict comprehension thingy:

```
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)
confdict = {section: dict(parser.items(section)) for section in parser.sections()}
```

Answer (score 12):

The instance data for ConfigParser is stored internally as a nested dict. Instead of recreating it, you could just copy it.

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> p = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> p.read("sample_config.ini")
['sample_config.ini']
>>> p.__dict__
{'_defaults': {}, '_sections': {'A': {'y': '2', '__name__': 'A', 'z': '3', 'x': '1'}, 'B':         {'y': '2', '__name__': 'B', 'z': '3', 'x': '1'}}, '_dict': <type 'dict'>}
>>> d = p.__dict__['_sections'].copy()
>>> d
{'A': {'y': '2', '__name__': 'A', 'z': '3', 'x': '1'}, 'B': {'y': '2', '__name__': 'B', 'z': '3', 'x': '1'}}
```

**Edit:**

Alex Martelli's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220670/read-all-the-contents-in-ini-file-into-dictionary-with-python/3220891#3220891) is cleaner, more robust, and prettier. While this was the accepted answer, I'd suggest using his approach instead. See his comment to this solution for more info.

Comment: I'm always loath of accessing protected ("start-with-underscore") names of attributes (and the absurd complication of going through `__dict__` doesn't help at all -- `d=p._sections.copy()` is exactly equivalent, simpler, and more direct).  That's why I suggested in my answer the alternative of using a subclass instead -- subclasses are _expected_ to access protected attributes of the base class.  In C++ this is enforced; in Python, it isn't, but that's because users are supposed to be disciplined enough to not _need_ enforcement;-).

Answer (score 2):

How to parse ini file in py?

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/var/tmp/test.ini')
print config.get('DEFAULT', 'network')
```

Where test.ini file contain:

```
[DEFAULT]
network=shutup
others=talk
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to take care is, `ConfigParser` converts the key values to lowercase hence in case you are converting the config entries to a dictionary cross check your requirements. I faced a problem because of this. For me I was having camel-case keys hence, had to change some amount of code when I started using the dictionary instead of files. `ConfigParser.get()` method internally converts the key to lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

> suppose file: config.properties contains the following:

- k =v
- k2= v2
- k3= v3

> python code:

```
def read_config_file(file_path):
        with open(file=file_path, mode='r') as fs:
            return {k.strip(): v.strip() for i in [l for l in fs.readlines() if l.strip() != ''] for k, v in [i.split('=')]}


print('file as dic: ', read_config_file('config.properties'))
```

Answer (score -1):

from https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

```
def ConfigSectionMap(section):
dict1 = {}
options = Config.options(section)
for option in options:
    try:
        dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option)
        if dict1[option] == -1:
            DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
    except:
        print("exception on %s!" % option)
        dict1[option] = None
return dict1
```