# Getting file input into Python script for praw script

Tags: python, settings, config, praw

So I have a simple reddit bot set up which I wrote using the praw framework. The code is as follows:

```
import praw
import time
import numpy
import pickle

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "Gets the Daily General Thread from subreddit.")
print("Logging in...")
r.login()

words_to_match = ['sdfghm']

cache = []

def run_bot():
    print("Grabbing subreddit...")
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit("test")
    print("Grabbing thread titles...")
    threads = subreddit.get_hot(limit=10)
    for submission in threads:
        thread_title = submission.title.lower()
        isMatch = any(string in thread_title for string in words_to_match)
        if submission.id not in cache and isMatch:
            print("Match found! Thread ID is " + submission.id)
            r.send_message('FlameDraBot', 'DGT has been posted!', 'You are awesome!')
            print("Message sent!")
            cache.append(submission.id)
    print("Comment loop finished. Restarting...")


# Run the script
while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(20)
```

I want to create a file (text file or xml, or something else) using which the user can change the fields for the various information being queried. For example I want a file with lines such as :

```
Words to Search for = sdfghm
Subreddit to Search in = text
Send message to = FlameDraBot
```

I want the info to be input from fields, so that it takes the value after Words to Search for = instead of the whole line. After the information has been input into the file and it has been saved. I want my script to pull the information from the file, store it in a variable, and use that variable in the appropriate functions, such as:

```
words_to_match = ['sdfghm']
subreddit = r.get_subreddit("test")
r.send_message('FlameDraBot'....
```

So basically like a config file for the script. How do I go about making it so that my script can take input from a .txt or another appropriate file and implement it into my code?

Comment: Related: [Configuration files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078170/python-how-would-you-save-a-simple-settings-config-file/19078712#19078712)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's just a plain old Python config, which you [can implement in an ASCII file, or else YAML or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078170/python-how-would-you-save-a-simple-settings-config-file).

Create a subdirectory `./config`, put your settings in `./config/__init__.py`
Then `import config`.
Using PEP-18 compliant names, the file `./config/__init__.py` would look like:

```
search_string = ['sdfghm']
subreddit_to_search = 'text'
notify = ['FlameDraBot']
```

If you want more complicated config, just read the many other posts on that.