# Key, values under one header in .INI file

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

I have this code in Python which, given a dictionary, it writes the key:value fields in a config.ini file. The problem is that it keeps writing the header for each field.

```
import configparser

myDict = {'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'space'}

def createConfig(myDict):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    # the string below is used to define the .ini header/title
    config["myHeader"] = {}
    with open('myIniFile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            config["myHeader"] = {key: value}
            config.write(configfile)
```

This is the output of .ini file:

```
[myDict]
hello = world

[myDict]
hi = space
```

How can I get rid of double title `[myDict]` and have the result like this

```
[myDict]
hello = world
hi = space
```

?

The code to create the .ini in Python has been taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344196/creating-a-config-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get twice the header, because you write twice to the configfile. You should build a complete dict and write it in one single write:

```
def createConfig(myDict):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    # the string below is used to define the .ini header/title
    config["myHeader"] = {}
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        config["myHeader"][key] = value
    with open('myIniFile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
import configparser

myDict = {'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'space'}

def createConfig(myDict):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    # the string below is used to define the .ini header/title
    config["myHeader"] = {}
    with open('myIniFile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config["myHeader"].update(myDict)
        config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: also this works. less verbose and less code. grazie.

Answer (score 0):

You could just to this:

```
def createConfig(myDict):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config["myIniFile"] = myDict
    with open('myIniFile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```