# Python ConfigParser use defaults if not in configuration file

Tags: python, default, configparser

What's the best way to use a default value if it isn't defined in a configuration file?  E.g. in the example below, perhaps only `listen_address` is defined in the configuration, and `listen_port` is absent.

I'm trying something like this:

```
import ConfigParser
from os.path import isfile

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set default values
    listen_address = '127.0.0.1'
    listen_port = 8000

    # Check for configurations from file and override defaults
    configFile = './configuration.ini'
    if isfile(configFile):
        configs = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        configs.read(configFile)
        try:
            listen_address = configs.get('ServerConfigs', 'listen_address')
        except:
            pass
        try:
            listen_port = configs.get('ServerConfigs', 'listen_port')
        except:
            pass
```

But that feels ugly.

Comment: If the parameter is not present in the configuration file, will the attempted assignment result in the variable being unset? I'm not at my computer, so can't test right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the built-in fallback parameter found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.get) that is used if it cannot find the option:

```
listen_address = configs.get('ServerConfigs', 'listen_address', fallback='127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: I'm keeping this marked as the answer since it was submitted a little before the other one with the same solution.  However, I found just now that it is not supported in 2.7.    Are there other options for 2.7?

Comment: Is there a way to have fallback values when loading from JSON files? Didn't see anything in the docs yet https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#fallback-values

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#fallback-values

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set default values
    listen_address = '127.0.0.1'
    listen_port = 8000

    # Check for configurations from file and override defaults
    configFile = './configuration.ini'
    if isfile(configFile):
        try:
            configs = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
            configs.read(configFile)
            listen_address = configs.get('ServerConfigs', 'listen_address', fallback=listen_address)
            listen_port = configs.get('ServerConfigs', 'listen_port', fallback=listen_port)
        except configparser.Error:
            # do whatever u want
            pass
```