# optimal solution to run a python script on multiple aws accounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to run a python script through multiple aws accounts using boto3 sdk. I have a user who has roles in multiple aws accounts. I was going to utilize sts and iterate through each accounts ARN in order to assume roles into each account and preform the task. However I don’t want to hardcode the account ID & role names which is used for the ARN. Would the most optimal solution be to store this data into a file( maybe a json file) and then pull the account data from there to assume the roles?

Config json file & hardcoding the roles account ids/role names

Comment: Ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078170/python-how-would-you-save-a-simple-settings-config-file).

Comment: Also be aware of possible open source projects for automation across accounts e.g. [awsrun](https://github.com/fidelity/awsrun).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to my mind off the top of my head:

1.) Use the Python Decouple package and keep the sensitive values in a ‘.env’ file.

You’ll install the Python Decouple package with:

```
pip install python-decouple
```

Then create a .env file and place your sensitive values in there like so:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<value>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<value>
```

Note: Don’t use quotation marks in the values, and obviously add the file to your .gitignore

Then to obtain the value in your script you’ll need to import config from decouple

```
from decouple import config
```

To reference the variable in your script you do it like so:

```
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
```

You can now freely use this variable in your script

2.) The second method that comes to mind is to create multiple profiles in the aws cli

To see which profiles you have currently use:

```
aws configure list-profiles
```

Create a profile for each role:

```
aws configure -—profile <profile_name>
```

You will then be prompted to input your access key id, secret access, key, default region, and default output format.

To reference the profile in the boto3 script use:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=‘profile_1’)
```

Depending on what your script looks like, you can then iterate through all of the profiles you need. Maybe something like this:

```
profiles = ['profile1', 'profile2', 'profile3']

for profile in profiles:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    # Then something like this:
    ec2 = session.client(‘ec2’)
    # Rest of your code
```

You can check out the boto3 documentation in the link below describing the second method

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html