# How to make an 'ini' file in a git repo only available locally?

Tags: python, git, ini

I don't want to push my ini file to git repository and i want to read ini file from local machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read and write INI file with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python)

Comment: @McGrady My question is little bit different...I don't want to push ini file to git repo and I need to read ini file from local machine. Is it possible? From git repo to my local path

Comment: @raghavendrat use .gitignore file

Comment: @sideffect0 Can u explain with example please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore any file to be added or pushed to remote repository use `.gitignore`
file.
In your case use create a file named `.gitignore` in project directory with,

```
# .gitignore file
*.ini
```

on git if you already added or staged the file,

```
git reset HEAD <path to ini file>
```

to remove file; dont forget to add `.gitignore` to git !