# can python read .ini file like php Yaconf

Tags: php, python, ini

php Yaconf can read .ini file

```
a=123
b=45
c.e.f=987
```

output like

```
['a' => 123]
['b' => 45]
['c' =>['e'=>['f'=>987]]]
```

can python read like this?

thx

---

Hi, All, May be I did not describe the question well, Sorry for that

Firstly, I did tried configparser, which just parse config `key=value`. 
But I would have config like `a.b.c=value`, e.g:

```
[cache]
redis.master.host='10.10.10.10'
redis.master.port='6379'
redis.master.auth='xxxx'
redis.slave_1.host='10.10.10.12'
redis.slave_1.port='6389'
redis.slave_1.auth='xxxx'
```

So, I would read config like

```
cfger.get('cache', 'redis')
```

and hope get result like

```
{'redis': {
    'master': {
           'host': '10.10.10.10',
           'port': '6379',
           'auth': 'xxxx',
        },
     'slave_1': {
           'host': '10.10.10.12',
           'port': '6389',
           'auth': 'xxxx',
        },
     }
}
```

Hope you can know what I said

Comment: It certainly could, if you programmed it to do so. Have you tried something you could show us?

Comment: @LysandrosNikolaou thx for your reply!  I have tried configparser. however, it just parse key=value, not key1.key2.key3=value

Comment: maybe this could be helpful (4th answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3

Comment: I think what you are looking for is sections in .ini files. You should take a look at [configObj](http://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#the-config-file-format).

Comment: @Tony_Wang, Lysandros is right: The answer to the **question you asked** is "configparser". If it doesn't solve the problem you have, **edit your question** to ask more clearly, and be sure to demonstrate why `configparser` fails. (Did you try `configparser`? What happened? Answer both questions if you edit your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I will not go so deep. Use belove snippet as boilerplate.

```
$ cat some.ini 
a=123
b=45
c.e.f=987

...
>>>h = {}
>>>l = []
>>> with open('some.ini') as inifile:
...     for lines in inifile.readlines():
...         k,v = lines.split('=')
...         h[k] = int(v)
...         # or l.append([lines.strip()])  
>>> h
{'a': 123, 'c.e.f': 987, 'b': 45}
```

the only thing you have to do is, parse 'c.e.f' to a nested dict.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Does any package or module could do just like Yaconf in PHP?