# Behave: Accessing context.config variables outside of step definitions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-behave

I am can't find out a way how to init my `ApiClient` with the value of `context.config.userdata['url']` from behave.ini

**behave.ini**

```
[behave.userdata]
url=http://some.url
```

**steps.py**

```
from behave import *
from client.api_client import ApiClient

# This is where i want to pass the config.userdata['url'] value
api_calls = ApiClient('???') 


@given('I am logged as "{user}" "{password}"')
def login(context, user, password):
    context.auth_header = api_calls.auth(user, password)
```

**api_client.py**

```
class ApiClient(object):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def auth(self, email, password):
        auth_payload = {'email': email, 'password': password}
        auth_response = requests.post(self.url + '/api/auth/session', auth_payload)

        return auth_response.text
```

Comment: Is the problem reading the ini file? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3 help?

Comment: No, I can read the ini file and access the data from it in my step defs. Though I have no clue how to access it outside of the steps so I could use values from it when initializing ApiClient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, in your `behave.ini`, **formatting matters**. That is, make note of the spaces:

```
[behave.userdata]
url = http://some.url
```

Second, instead of creating your ApiClient object in your `/features/steps/steps.py`, you *should* be creating it within your `/features/environment.py`. What's this `environment.py`? If you don't know, it's basically a file that defines what should happen before/during/after your test runs. See [here](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#environmental-controls) for more details.

Essentially, you would have something like:

**environment.py**

```
from client.api_client import ApiClient

""" 
The code within the following block is checked before all/any of test steps are run.
This would be a great place to instantiate any of your class objects and store them as
attributes in behave's context object for later use.
"""
def before_all(context):         
    # The following creates an api_calls attribute for behave's context object
    context.api_calls = ApiClient(context.config.userdata['url'])
```

Later, when you want to use your ApiClient object, you could do it like so:

**steps.py**

```
from behave import *

@given('I am logged as "{user}" "{password}"')
def login(context, user, password):
    context.api_calls.auth(user, password)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old question but the answer is not current. No spaces seem to be required in the current documentation and OP's issue is the header tag. It must be `[behave]`

https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html