# need help write list to config.ini

Tags: python, for-loop

my_list

```
x = [a, b, c, d]
```

config.ini

```
[var_list]
var01 = a1
var02 = b1
var03 = c1
var04 = d1
var05 = e1
var06 = f1
```

I need to write x[] to ini file
and in this case, I have only 4 variables in list but I have 6 variables to keep in ini file I need to write to 'N/A' to other variables left like this

config.ini (result)

```
[var_list]
var01 = a
var02 = b
var03 = c
var04 = d
var05 = N/A
var06 = N/A
```

I have no idea how to coding in for loop or something?
Thank you and sorry about bad in englist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3)

Comment: I need to use loop because In future its will behave more than 100+ variable

Comment: How do you define the names of the variables? Instead of a `list` I see this to be a better case for `dict` though. Or even JSON.