# Best way to read aws credentials file

Tags: python, boto3, boto

In my python code I need to extract AWS credentials
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
which are stored in the plain text file as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-format.html

I know the name of the file:  AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE
and the name of profile: AWS_PROFILE.

My current approach is to read and parse this file in python by myself to get AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.

But I hope there is already standard way to get it using boto3 or some other library.
Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a reason you are parsing this manually rather than using something like `session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev'` as [described here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)?

Comment: Mark, I need to invoke Hive script from Python and pass  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID to it as hiveconfig

Comment: Yeah, may be easier to parse the file. FWIW, the session object has a `get_credentials()` method. So `session.get_credentials().access_key` and `session.get_credentials().secret_key` do what you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something like this work for you, or am I misunderstanding the question? Basically start a session for the appropriate profile (or the default, I guess), and then query those values from the credentials object:

```pyhon
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=<...your-profile...>)
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    print("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = {}".format(credentials.access_key))
    print("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = {}".format(credentials.secret_key))
    print("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = {}".format(credentials.token))
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the AWS credentials file uses a standard INI file format. You can utilize `configparser` to parse the file easily. Please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html.

For boto3, if you put it in standard areas, it will load automagically.

> Boto3 will look in several locations when searching for credentials.
> The mechanism in which Boto3 looks for credentials is to search
> through a list of possible locations and stop as soon as it finds
> credentials. The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:
>
> 1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method Passing
> 2. credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
> 3. Environment variables
> 4. **Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)**
> 5. **AWS config file (~/.aws/config)**
> 6. Assume Role provider
> 7. **Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)**
> 8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Comment: I need to invoke Hive script from Python and pass AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID to it as hiveconf