# How to setup an AWS role which can auto refresh AccessToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using a mix of profiles and roles from boto3 Python library to interact with S3 buckets.
I see aws profile's AccessToken doesn't expire but one of the roles we are assuming using this profile does expire in 1 hour.

So I wanted to check if there is an option to setup the role in a way that it refreshes AccessToken token if it expires. I have found that there is option to extend SessionDuration for an AWS role in AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-managingrole-editing-console.html)
but couldn't find if it's possible to auto refresh AccessToken itself when it expires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh the boto3 credetials when python script is running indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724485/how-to-refresh-the-boto3-credetials-when-python-script-is-running-indefinitely)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Paolo. But I was looking more from AWS admin side. I am trying to use your suggested resource though as it seems what I was looking for is not possible to be set up by admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way to have an IAM role automatically refresh the tokens.  You have two options with regard to persistent credentials.

#1. Write a script that refreshes your credentials in the background so that when your main script needs credentials they are always fresh.

#2. Create a "service account" (IAM User) with static credentials with least privileges for your activity.  They will never expire.

If you go with option #2, you should create a process for rotating the credentials on a regular basis.