# Experiencing expired token errors when uploading files to AWS S3 using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, credentials

I'm uploading the files like so:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.upload_file(img_path, bucket, key)
```

The uploading code is in a loop and that loop is processing a lot of data, so this entire process will take a few days. I'm using multiprocessing as well.

Anyway, I'm noticing that after some time has passed I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to upload image.JPEG: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling 
the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired.: image.JPEG
```

I've heard that the credentials are refreshed or something periodically. I'm not sure how to solve this though.

---

#### Edit

Voting to close because I found a working solution in [the SO answer I posted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226170/7766024).

Comment: Are you using temporary credentials?

Comment: @jordanm Might be a dumb question, but how do I know if the credentials are temporary? As far as I know I have a file at `~/.aws/credentials` that contains my Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, and a Session Token. I believe that Boto3 reads that for the credentials.

Comment: Session token is an indication it's temporary. How does the session token get updated? Are you using assume-role or SSO?

Comment: @jordanm I don't believe that there's any code that updates the token; the only S3 related pieces of code are the lines I put in my OP.

Comment: You say that the `credentials` file contains a Session Token. This is an indication that they are "temporary credentials". How did you obtain the Access Key, Secret Key and Session Token?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Ah. Those were provided to me by the company's system administrator. I believe that we're using IAM roles for our organization.

Comment: When a user [assumes an IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html), a new set of **temporary credentials** are provided. These default to **10 minutes** of validity but can be generated up to 12 hours of validity.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks. Upon reading [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75890127/7766024) it seems that I could try and re-instantiate the Boto3 client object whenever I encounter the error. I'll try that and see if the script terminates or not and will edit and close the OP accordingly.

Comment: That won't help since you have hard-coded the credentials. If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance with an IAM Role assigned to the instance, then the credentials will be automatically generated without having to store anything in the `credentials` file. If you are running on your own computer, the typical method is to store your long-term IAM User credentials using `aws configure` (which puts them in the `credentials` file). If you need to assume a role, then your code would use those credentials to call `AssumeRole`, which would return temporary credentials you can use.