# Point to the location of the alembic.ini file to the python file

Tags: python, alembic

I wanted use alembic.ini file in my python. That is I wanted to show the compiler that my .ini file is locating in this place.
My project struture is

```
| my_project/
    | migrations
       |alembic.ini
       |versions
         |xxxxxx_.py
       |env.py
    |my_file.py
```

I am running the `my_file.py` and I want to point the location on the `alembic.ini` file. I tried using this link [How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3)
by importing configparser. But no use.
Since it's ini file I cannot import it. Let me know is there any to import it.