# How can I read INI file in Python without configparser?

Tags: json, python-3.x, readfile, ini

I have INI file, it contains next:

```
{
   "input": {
      "json": "good.json",
      "csv": "good.csv",
      "encoding": "utf-8"
   },
   "output": {
      "fname": "res.txt",
      "encoding": "utf-8"
   }
}
```

so basically inside ini file I have json. I can no find a way to work with keys inside the file without using configparser . Please help

Comment: Use the `configparser` module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just opening it as a json file? Since the `ini` file is a text file, it should * just work *

```
import json

# I saved your example in a text file called test.ini and 
# put it in the same folder as this script
with open('test.ini', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

The contents of your `ini` file will be in `data`, which will be a dictionary.

Comment: `json` is a built-in package so it should be available to you

Comment: I truly did few times but it always returned an error. well, maybe I had to bother people first.  now it is perfectly working, thanks !

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure if my answer worked based on your comment? But if it did I'd appreciate it if you could accept it!