# Updating yaml file using PyYaml

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to update a yaml file in place with values that are rendered from a shell script. The fields I am trying to update is **upassword** and **schema**. My yaml is slightly different from regular yaml

Here is how my Yaml looks like:

```
# values.conf

[first]
# First user
server_host = xxx.com
server_port = 1432
schema = get
uname = CN=svc-xxx-090
upassword =

[auth]
# default to /etc/.passwd in packaged installations and ./passwds in
# tarball installations.
#passwd_file =
passwd_db = pass.db
enabled=True
```

I need this yaml to be updated to:

```
# values.conf

[first]
# First user
server_host = xxx.com
server_port = 1432
schema = put
uname = CN=svc-xxx-090
upassword = 5668guuh6y%&_jhv86@

[auth]
# default to /etc/.passwd in packaged installations and ./passwds in
# tarball installations.
#passwd_file =
passwd_db = pass.db
enabled=True
```

I have regular yamls that I am using and able to update them without any issues but this yaml drives me crazy. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a YAML format, it is an ini / cfg format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3)