# How to transfer content from config.ini file to csv file in a logical format?

Tags: python, csv, configuration-files, ini

Is there anyway that I can retrieved my config file content and display the necessary content in a logical format using `for` loop?

```
[_1_ubu]
control_name = 1.1 Ensure AppArmor is installed
outcome = PASS
sys_out = Status: install ok installed
expected_out = AppArmor is installed
remediation = apt install apparmor
severity = MEDIUM

[_2_ubu]
control_name = 1.2 Ensure Avahi Server is not installed
outcome = FAIL
sys_out = Status: install ok installed
expected_out = avahi-daemon is installed
remediation = apt purge avahi-daemon
severity = MEDIUM

[_3_ubu]
control_name = 1.3 Ensure CUPS is not installed
outcome = PASS
sys_out = not installed
expected_out = cups is not installed
remediation = apt purge cups
severity = MEDIUM
```

In a structure like this:

[image: Screenshot of desired results]

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: You could use `configparser` and `csv`. Setup a CSV DictWriter. Then use the config parser's `section` method to enumerate sections and its `items` method to read each section's options. Turn the items into a dict and pass to the writer.

Comment: You could do it by using the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module to read the INI data and the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to write it out in CSV format.

Comment: My suggestion assumes that the entire INI follows the pattern given. It would not be a general ini-to-csv solution because most INI's have a different structure per section.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example to read the `.ini` file and write it to `.csv` file:

```py
import pandas as pd
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("input.ini")

df = pd.DataFrame([config[s] for s in config.sections()])
print(df)

df.to_csv("result.csv", index="False")
```

Prints:

```
                               control_name               expected_out outcome             remediation severity                       sys_out
0          1.1 Ensure AppArmor is installed      AppArmor is installed    PASS    apt install apparmor   MEDIUM  Status: install ok installed
1  1.2 Ensure Avahi Server is not installed  avahi-daemon is installed    FAIL  apt purge avahi-daemon   MEDIUM  Status: install ok installed
2          1.3 Ensure CUPS is not installed      cups is not installed    PASS          apt purge cups   MEDIUM                 not installed
```

and saves `result.csv`.

Comment: You're a savior it works like about what i was intending. Can you please explain how does the structure works as ive not used pandas library. I can't believe that it only takes few lines of coding to achieve that format. Also, if i want the header(control_name, outcome) to be bold, how do i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Once you can have it in a pandas dataframe it would only be necessary to save it as ".csv", look at these answers similar to your question:

[How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3)