# Read config file in python

Tags: python, configuration

I would like to read following config file having IPs defined for workers and managers. I tried configparser module but it requires key-value pairs. Anyone has any idea to read the below file using python, I would be thankful.

```
[managers]
1.2.3.4
[workers]
2.3.45.5
3.5.6.7
5.7.8.9
```

File may have random number of IPs.

Comment: `with open("path/to/your/file.ext") as f:` and then parse the file. It's quite easy to find out where a "section" begins, so it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to parse this into a dict.

Comment: you may wish to have a look at [configparser — Configuration file parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). See also [Read all the contents in ini file into dictionary with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220670/read-all-the-contents-in-ini-file-into-dictionary-with-python)

Comment: all these solutions are talking about key value pairs. however, I dont have any key value pair in my config file. If I understood your solution wrongly, please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

If you reformat your data file as follows, you can then use `configparser` module to parse it. You can install it by doing `pip install configparser`

**Data file**

```
[managers]
ip = 1.2.3.4
[workers]
ip = 2.3.45.5
     3.5.6.7
     5.7.8.9
```

**Sample Usage**

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
# from ConfigParser import ConfigParser # for python3 
data_file = 'tmp.txt'

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(data_file)

config.sections()
# ['managers', 'workers']

config['managers']['ip']
# '1.2.3.4'

config['workers']['ip']
#'2.3.45.5\n3.5.6.7\n5.7.8.9'

config['workers']['ip'].splitlines()
#['2.3.45.5', '3.5.6.7', '5.7.8.9']
```

Comment: ...Above solution is giving me errors like `AttributeError:  instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`. I am using `python 2.7`. Do I need to add extra things in the above solution ??

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar. Above code works fine for me on both python2.7 and python3. Can you try again by importing configparser as `from backports.configparser import ConfigParser`

Comment: @Sunitha..Yes its working for me too.  Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
res = {}
temp = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:                      #Iterate over each line
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("["):             #Check if line is header
            line = line.strip("[]")
            res[line] = []                   #Create Key
            temp.append(line)
        else:
            res[temp[-1]].append(line)        #Append Values.
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'workers': ['2.3.45.5', '3.5.6.7', '5.7.8.9'], 'managers': ['1.2.3.4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is using `typed-settings` and `ipaddress`.

1. Install `typed-settings`: `pip install typed-settings`.
2. Create a `toml` file named `config.toml`.

```toml
[managers]
ip = ["1.2.3.4"]

[workers]
ip = ["2.3.45.5", "3.5.6.7", "5.7.8.9"]
```

3. Define the data model class and load it.

```python
import ipaddress
import typed_settings as ts


@ts.settings(frozen=True)
class Mangers:
    ip = ts.option(converter=lambda l: [ipaddress.ip_address(i) for i in l])


@ts.settings(frozen=True)
class Workers:
    ip = ts.option(converter=lambda l: [ipaddress.ip_address(i) for i in l])


managers_settings = ts.load(Mangers, appname="managers", config_files=["config.toml"])
workers_settings = ts.load(Workers, appname="workers", config_files=["config.toml"])
print(managers_settings)
print(workers_settings)

# Mangers(ip=[IPv4Address('1.2.3.4')])
# Workers(ip=[IPv4Address('2.3.45.5'), IPv4Address('3.5.6.7'), IPv4Address('5.7.8.9')])
```